# How to check if I destroyed the bluetooth receiver

Tags: bluetooth, usb-device, usb-c, adapter, receiver

I have very little experience with electronics but I tried converting my Logitech unifying receiver to USB-C.
I followed the steps I found online and got a functioning result. I based my wiring on the table on this site [Somanytech](https://somanytech.com/usb-c-3-0-wiring-diagram-schematics-assembly-diagram-usb-c-color-code/). I shorted A5/B5 to ground with 4.7kOhm resistors which should've been 5.1kOhm, but the guides I read mentioned that a 10% tolerance was allowed.
The Mouse actually worked simply by plugging in the modified receiver and the USB device was recognized in the device manager.
Sadly when I tested the receiver the next day, Windows showed no reaction to a new USB device and the mouse didn't connect.
I'm not sure what went wrong but I did touch some of the leads with my fingers while unplugging, could that destroy the circuit?
I am planning on trying again, so my question is if there is a way to check if either USB-A or -C board were damaged using a multi-meter.
What leads do I have to check?
If it makes it easier I still have a functioning receiver against which I could compare the readings.

During assembly I did not use any flux and ensured that none of the connection where shorted using the beeping function of the multi-meter.

Excuse my rough schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgaUgD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Windows can be a bit flaky with USB devices. Sometimes, after a USB device is inserted, Windows loses connectivity. You might test the circuit in another PC, Linux or Windows, to see if the issue was in OS, which I believe is more likely than hardware damage, if no more was done to the cicuit than you described. You could also try clearing the OS list of connected USB devices: https://www.wikihow.com/Clear-the-Record-of-USB-Plug-in-Equipment

Comment: The Unifying Receiver is not Bluetooth but something else. Since you only connected one side of USB pins on the flippable Type-C connector, it only works if you plug it in the correct orientation but not in the other. Did you try both orientations? You know you can just buy adapters that allow you to plug in Type-A devices into Type-C ports? Or did you tear down the module and tried to hack it together yourself with a Type-C plug? One mistake with dangly wires and the laptop is beyond repair. Much safer to buy an adapter.

Comment: The main goal was to get it into a smaller formfactor so I wouldn't have to carry around a converter or could use it for other devices.
According to the datasheet of the USB-C board I bought, the B6 & B7 pins are already internally wired through A6/A7 respectively, so I thought it should be flippable, which I did try out.
Thank you for the insight though, I didn't know there was such a risk from plugging in a USB-device.